# json schema to pojo generator

Tags: java, json

what is the best json to pojo generator which have oneof/allof/anyof features . We are currently using a custom one which doesn't support the latest additions in the json. I have tried some of them that shows in the google search but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I use  https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator for schema validation and jackson for pojo-generator.
However, I did not find any support for allOf/AnyOf/oneOf explicitly in jackson. But jackson has a rich set of annotation and it can be built using those. 
you can refer a discussion https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/392 to see if something helpful is there for you.

Comment: we are already using custom generator with allof. jsonschema2pojo doesn't support this as of now. Any way appreciate your help :)

Comment: @jAvA How did you handle this scenario ?